# Enviar endereço para pesquisar no google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Olá, Peço ajuda no seguinte:
Eu tenho um TextView com um endereço, eu gostaria que quando clicasse fizesse uma Intent enviando este endereço para pesquisar no próprio App do Google Maps do usuário.

Sei que posso usar o API do Google Maps, mas gostaria de saber se é possível enviar o endereço para o Google Maps do aplicativo do usuario.

Obrigada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exemplos de uso citados no https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Pesquisar restaurantes próximos:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Pesquisar restaurantes em São Paulo Capital (baseado por uma geo-localização especifica):

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:-23.564175,-46.6617916?q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Localizar um endereço descrito:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=Avenida São João - República, São Paulo - SP");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Com o `TextView` deve ficar assim:

```
TextView searchTextField = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.searchTextField);

Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + searchTextField.getText().toString());
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: Oi Guilherme, muito obrigada! Já me deu até o código do TextView. Funcionou que é uma beleza!