# Filtro no Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de filtrar os locais como por exemplo "academias" usando Google Places ?
Pois a idéia é pegar e utilizar os dados desses locais.

Comment: Existe sim Eric. Mas você quer filtrar pelo que?! Tem como detalhar melhor sua dúvida editando a questão?

Comment: Ack Lay, editei a pergunta.

Comment: Guilherme,  o problema é que estou usando o Places Picker e acho que não funcionaria do jeito do outro post. =/ "Dei uma olhada no outro post e considero não ser duplicada rs"

Comment: @EricAndrade retirei o voto de fechamento, irei tentar criar um exemplo com Picker.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Beleza, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que resposta do Guilherme de como [Enviar endereço para pesquisar no Google Maps](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169604/35406) te atende bem, porém precisaria de alguns detalhes sobre os [Tipos de locais](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=pt-br) que o Google Place permite para busca.

Esta página possui uma lista de valores permitidos para a propriedade `types` na [**Google Places API**](https://developers.google.com/places/?hl=pt-br). A [Tabela 1](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=pt-br#table1) lista os tipos que podem ser usados em pesquisas e adições de local. [A Tabela 2](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=pt-br#table2) lista os tipos adicionais que podem ser retornados nos resultados de pesquisas de local. A [Tabela 3](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=pt-br#table3) lista os tipos que podem ser usados em solicitações de preenchimento automático de local.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde.

Depois de pesquisar bastante, achei esse tutorial:

http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-nearby-places-api-using-retrofit-android/

Se trata de chamadas de serviços com Retrofit + Maps.

Valeu ai ! =)